# Compare two arrays and remove array from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I need remove from bigger array smaller

```
$a = array(223 => 6, 381 => 6);
```

and second arrays is:

```
$b = array(array('id' => 45, 'username' => 'rock'), array('id' => 223, 'username' => 'pop'), array('id' => 381, 'username' => 'stock'));
```

With print_r() they looks like this

```
Array
(
    [223] => 6
    [381] => 6
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 45
            [username] => rock
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 223
            [username] => pop
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 381
            [username] => stock
        )

)
```

How do I remove from $b array where id != $a[keys]
So in result I will have array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 223
            [username] => pop
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 381
            [username] => stock
        )

)
```

I try to use array_diff, array_search and unset but do not know how make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you want to filter out the values where no `$a[$sub_array["id"]]` exists, where `$sub_array` is an element of `$b`:

Then [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) is what you search:

```
$array = array_filter($b, function ($val) use ($a) {
    return isset($a[$val["id"]]);
});
```

Comment: your varian is more cleaner but it shows this error

array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array

Comment: @user3375344 true, that's because I didn't respect parameter order; fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $a = array(223 => 6, 381 => 6);
    $b = array(array('id' => 45, 'username' => 'rock'), array('id' => 223, 'username' => 'pop'), array('id' => 381, 'username' => 'stock'));
    $keys = array_keys($a);
    $new_array = array();
    for ($i = 0, $len = count($b); $i < $len; $i++) {
        $c = $b[$i];
        if (in_array($c['id'], $keys)) {
            $new_array[] = $c;
        }
    }
    var_dump($new_array);
```

Comment: Check out bwoebi's answer for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array(223 => 6, 381 => 6);
$b = array(array('id' => 45, 'username' => 'rock'), array('id' => 223, 'username' => 'pop'), array('id' => 381, 'username' => 'stock'));
$cc = 0;
foreach($b as $bb)
{
    $flag = 0;
    foreach($a as $k => $aa)
    {
        if($bb['id'] == $k)
        {
            $flag=1;
        }
    }
    if($flag == 0)
    {
        unset($b[$cc]);
    }
    $cc++;
}
print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want first to use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get all the keys from $a. Then loop through $b and with [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) you will know if id is a $a key. Finally use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```
$a = array(223 => 6, 381 => 6);
$aKey = array_keys($a);
$b = array(array('id' => 45, 'username' => 'rock'), array('id' => 223, 'username' => 'pop'), array('id' => 381, 'username' => 'stock'));
foreach ($b as $key => $value)
    if (!in_array($value['id'], $aKey))
        unset($b[$key]);
print_r($b);
```

Comment: `array_keys` obviates the need for your first loop.